# UpdateMany gives a error: 'Collection' object is not callable

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to update the document my query for it is:

```
def database_connection():
    myclient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    mydb = myclient["test"]
    return mydb
db=database_connection()
collection = db.collection_name




collection.updateMany({"name":"xyz"},{"$set":{'name':'abc'}})
```

but it is giving me error

```
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'updateMany' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

Comment: What is the type of `collection`?

Comment: My collection has string and array type document

Comment: My sample code on [github here](https://github.com/namgivu/mongo-start/blob/master/query-tutorial.python/common.py#L6) may be useful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick for you i.e. `update_many()` instead of updateMany()

```
def database_connection():
    myclient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    mydb = myclient["test"]
    return mydb
db=database_connection()
collection.update_many({"name":"xyz"},{"$set":{'name':'abc'}})
```